# What happened to Last.FM radio service in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

My Last.FM stations stopped working last week - I assume it is due to their protocol upgrade:

> We're writing you to let you know that there will soon be a change to Last.fm radio that may affect you. Our stats show that you've listened to radio through an application that uses our old streaming protocol. On 1 December we will deprecate this old protocol, so in some applications radio will no longer work.

I updated to the latest version of Rhythmbox (2.98) with the webupd8team PPA, but still no luck.

Does anybody have this working?  If so, what did you do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Last.FM has brought some changes to their radio services. Here's a [relevant quote from their blog post.](http://www.last.fm/announcements/radio2013)

> - In the United States, United Kingdom and Germany, radio in the desktop client is now a subscription feature, as it is elsewhere.
> - In Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Ireland and Brazil, there will be no significant changes to our service.
> - Unfortunately, in all other countries, we are no longer offering a radio service after this date.

Going forward from 15 January 2013 onwards, the radio service will be a subscription feature available to the countries **United States, United Kingdom, Germany, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Ireland and Brazil**.

For all the other countries, there won't be any radio streaming available since the above mentioned date.

Comment: Great.  May as well use Pandora now.  That's really trashy - classic "bait and switch" tactic.  Last.fm started by offering free streaming to desktop clients so they could build up their user base, and then switches to the paid service once you've spent a bunch of time adding stations and preferences.

Comment: Why do not try Spotify? It is far better than last.fm!