# Howto play Last.fm on Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

So after authenticating with last.fm, the last.fm drop-down menu is populated but when attempting to listen to a station nothing is happening. I'm hoping that I'm just not doing something right.. Let me know askubuntu in newb detail howto get this thing playn last.fm music please. :)

Answer (score 2):

Last.fm is now a [subscription service](http://www.last.fm/announcements/radio2013), so won't stream within Rhythmbox "for free". Took me a while to work this out, and comments about [bait-and-switch](https://askubuntu.com/a/238054/38585) are about right, it seems to me.

Comment: P.s. If you have wide-ranging tastes, give [Radio Paradise](http://www.radioparadise.com/) a listen.